# Sending images in chat using strophe js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I am developing a web based chat application using Strophe js. I am using Ejabberd XMPP Server. I went through the plugins provided by strophe js but I dint found any plugin to send/receive images. I searched all kind of questions but dint find any perfect answer. How can and send images to other user using strophe js?? Is there any direct way of plugin to do that??

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in XMPP, sending images is about doing file transfer. This is not really convenient to do in a browser. You should look into a solution based on custom XMPP signalling and HTTP file upload / download.

Comment: I went through with the strophe plugins and i found [si-filetransfer](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/si-filetransfer) plugin. Can I use this plugin to play with the file transfer??

Comment: From what its look, this module is for Stream Initiation (negotiation), not transferring the file itself.

Comment: Ok then what about [this](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/ibb)?? Can I use this plugin to do file transfer??

Comment: You can try, but as I mentioned, I think it will be incomplete and will not perform the file transfer itself

Comment: Okay. So finally I understand is the file transfer should be done without the plugins. Could you please give me some idea of sending the images ??